# Sine inequality: How to prove that $|\sin(x)| \le |x|$ for $ x \in \mathbb{R}$

Tags: calculus, trigonometry, inequality

Following [Wolfram Sine inequalities](http://functions.wolfram.com/ElementaryFunctions/Sin/29/) I found that

$$|\sin(x)| \le |x| \quad \text{for}  \quad x \in \mathbb{R}$$
How can I prove this relation?

Comment: How do you define $\sin x$?

Comment: I notice the question is the seventh formula on the linked page. Were you able to prove all six of the formulas that came before this one? In particular, do you have any question about proving that $\sin x \leq x$ when $x\geq0$?

Comment: @DavidK I just hat to use the seventh formula and felt insecure using it ;)

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen can you give me a hint on what definitions there are for the Sin? I would define it over the Taylor-expansion like `\sin(x) = x - x^3/3! + x^5/5! ...`

Answer (score 19, accepted):

If $x\in\mathbb R$, $\bigl|\sin'(x)\bigr|=\bigl|\cos(x)\bigr|\leqslant1$. Therefore, by the mean value theorem,$$\bigl|\sin(x)\bigr|=\bigl|\sin(x)-\sin(0)\bigr|\leqslant1\times|x-0|=|x|.$$

Comment: The function $|\sin x |$ is not differentiable anywhere. However, the inequality is trivial at such points. Nevertheless differentiate $\sin x$ and then use MVT. This is more correct version of your solution.

Comment: @szw1710 I never claimed that $\bigl|\sin(x)\bigr|$ is differentiable everywhere. The only function that I differentiated was the sine function.

Comment: I'm curious. What did you assume when you differentiated $\sin(x)$?

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt I assumed that $\sin'(x)=\cos(x)\in[-1,1]$.

Comment: But how did you conclude $\sin'(x)=\cos(x)$?

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos, yes, you are right. Maybe you could formulate it in a better way (since $(\sin x)'=\cos x$ then ...). But... your solution is 100% correct. :)

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt What I concluded was that $\bigl|\sin'(x)\bigr|=\bigl|\cos(x)\bigr|$.

Comment: That's not my question. You claimed that you assumed $\sin'(x)=\cos(x)$. How did you reach this assumption?

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt That's a standard fact about the sine function.

Comment: Standard facts come from places. Unlike @szw1710 and the upvoters, I get the bad feeling that this "proof" of yours hinges on another standard fact about the sine function. One that makes this answer circular.

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt If, for instance, you define $\sin(x)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^n}{(2n+1)!}x^{2n+1}$ and $\cos(x)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^n}{(2n)!}x^n$, then it is easy to prove (assuming standard facts about power series) that $\sin'=\cos$. Do you see anything circular in this approach?

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos Nothing is circular in that approach, but then I'd like you to prove $|\cos(x)|\le1$ from that.

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt $(\sin^2+\cos^2)'=2\sin\sin'+2\cos\cos'=2\sin\cos-2\cos\sin=0$. Therefore, $\sin^2+\cos^2$ is constant. Since $\sin(0)=0$ and $\cos(0)=1$, it follows that $\sin^2+\cos^2\equiv1$. Therefore, $(\forall x\in\mathbb{R}):\sin(x),\cos(x)\in[-1,1]$.

Comment: $\ddot\smile$ That's a nifty proof.

Answer (score 7):

Note that the sine of theta is less than the arc-length. Pretty standard approach to evaluating the limit:

$$\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\sin(x)}x$$

[image]

This proof is only valid for $0<x<\pi/2$. For angles beyond this, simply note that

$$|\sin(x)|\le1$$

and

$$\sin(x)\le x\implies|\sin(-x)|\le|-x|$$

Comment: based on the picture I agree that sin(x) is less than the arc length of x, is the proof of this based on the limit you mentioned (which is 1) or is there another way to show that this holds using geometry? (Maybe it's an obvious fact, which I'm not aware of.)

Comment: I'm using a geometric argument here, but I'm not really big on formal geometry proofs. An alternate approach, not using the lengths, would be to use the areas. You might prefer that instead.

Answer (score 3):

**Hint:)** $\cos u\leq1$ then for $x\geq0$
$$\displaystyle\int_0^x\cos udu\leq\int_0^xdu$$
and for $x\leq0$
$$\displaystyle\int_x^0\cos udu\leq\int_x^0du$$

Answer (score 1):

For $x>0$ define $g(x)=\sin x-x$ and show that $g$ decreases. For $x<0$ use oddiness of $g$. For $x=0$ it is trivial.

Comment: All you can conclude from $g(x)=\sin x-x$ for $x\gt0$ is that $\sin x\le |x|$. I think you also need to define $h(x)=\sin x+x$ and show that $h$ is increasing. Then you can conclude that $-|x|\le \sin x$ for all $x\gt 0$ as well.

Answer (score 0):

For x>=0 you can use corollary of Lagrange mean value theorem. Take f(x)= sinx -x  . Take derivative f'(x)= cosx -1 which is less than 0 and f(0)=0  which means f(x) is decreasing for all positive x. Sinx -x<0